# Anonymous class error

Tags: java, anonymous-class

```
public interface IMethodCallback 
{
    boolean Execute();
}

...

IMethodCallback callback = new IMethodCallback
            {
                boolean Execute()
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };
```

This results in errors. How can I make something like this in Java?

Answer (score 3):

You miss the parentheses of the constructor:

```
IMethodCallback callback = new IMethodCallback()
{
    public boolean Execute()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing  brackets `()`

```
IMethodCallback callback = new IMethodCsallback() {
          // your impl method
};
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted. Some parts of the world call `()` "brackets."

Comment: +1 This should not be downvoted!

Comment: @MattBall hehe, i am surprised, downvoter care to comment ?

Comment: Check @rgettman's answer. You are missing the `public`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis where did i even include the method in my answer ?. but you are right thou.

Comment: @PermGenError I didn't downvote. Just commenting that it's incomplete.

Comment: I downvoted as you didn't include what the brackets do. In my oppinion, answers should also explain what is missing semantically, not just syntactically.

Comment: @Femaref fair enough, but its clearly syntax error. what else can you say bout the brackets. however, if an answer is right and is not descriptive enough you just can't D/V it.

Comment: You can say it's the constructor that's missing.

Comment: @Femaref last time i checked Interfaces can't be instantiated and don't have constructors. :P, you could however say, "You are missing the sub-class of the interface (Anonymous class's) constructor call"

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you are missing the parentheses after `new IMethodCallback`.  But you also need to declare your implementation method `Execute()` `public`, because that's the method implementing your interface.  Methods in an interface are implicitly `public`.

```
IMethodCallback callback = new IMethodCallback()
{
    // Implements an interface; must be public
    public boolean Execute()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Methods in an interface are implicitly public and implementers cannot weaken access privileges.

Answer (score 1):

```
IMethodCallback callback = new IMethodCallback() //You have missed the parenthesis of constructor.
{
     public boolean Execute() {
         return false;
     }
 };
```

and follow the java naming convention (**Camel Case**)